# ErrorException Undefined variable: farmers (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\best\resources\views\farmers.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm new at Laravel 8 Livewire, I keep encountering this error,
**ErrorException Undefined variable: farmers (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\best\resources\views\farmers.blade.php)**
and I'm at wits end. Please help me fix it.

My Livewire Component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Farmer;

class Farmers extends Component
{
    
    public function render()
    {
        $farmers = Farmer::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return view('livewire.farmers', ['farmers'=>$farmers]);
    }
}
```

My farmers.blade.php file

```
 <table class="table table-compact table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">District</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ward</th>
                        <th scope="col">Village</th>
                        <th scope="col">FullName</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sex</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Contact</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heifers</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cows</th>
                        <th scope="col">Bulls</th>
                        <th scope="col">Steers</th>
                        <th scope="col">Calf</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @foreach ($farmers as $farmer)
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{$farmer->district}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->ward}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->village}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->fullname}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->sex}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->age}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->contact}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->heifers}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->cows}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->bulls}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->steers}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->calf}}</td>
                          <td>{{$farmer->total}}</td>
                         
                        </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

I've tried other suggested solutions such as calling the view as `return view('livewire.farmers', compact('farmers'));` but with no success

Comment: You render to `livewire.farmers`, but the error comes from `farmers` (outside the livewire directory). Different views.

Answer (score 0):

Livewire components work different.
You have to set the farmers variable as a public class property.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Farmer;

class Farmers extends Component
{
    
    public $farmers;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->farmers = Farmer::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return view('livewire.farmers');
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation for property bindings.
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties

Comment: The data can be passed through the `view()` method, the problem is that the view is different. `farmers.blade.php` vs `livewire/farmers.blade.php`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @Hiighsky, I've tried your solution but it still gives me the same error. I even tried clearing cache but still no change.

Comment: @Qirel, I'm not sure what exactly you mean, kindly put in simpler terms

Comment: Read my comment below your question. You are rendering one view, but accessing another. The view Livewire renders is `resources/views/livewire/farmers.blade.php`, while you are rendering/accessing `resources/views/farmers.blade.php`

Comment: I've corrected that and I'm now rendering ```resources/views/livewire/farmers.blade.php``` but I'm still getting the same **Undefined Variable: farmers** error